# Webapp OAuth integration with the facebook spotify integration

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, integration, spotify

We are facing an web application integration challenge that I could describe in great detail but an example is easier. We would like to link accounts of 2 very separate applications exactly how spotify accounts can be linked to facebook accounts. I'm not referring to how you can create a spotify account with a facebook login but linking your spotify account with a facebook account when separate accounts exist.

My understanding of OAuth is that the authorisation / authentication tokens are stored on the end user device (browser / cookies, app storage on mobile etc.) and that it is secure. It seems to me that spotify seems to be storing facebook authorisation tokens on their servers which seems to me to be a large security risk. The reason why I think this is that after I link my spotify account to my facebook account it is linked regardless of which client / device is used.

I have tried to find out in the internet how this works and have also inspect the browser application storage but cannot find out much information this way.

Comment: the standard user token for facebook is only valid for 2 hours, and it does not have THAT many permissions nowadays. there are also ways to protect tokens from using them elsewhere (see facebook docs about that).

Comment: To make it a bit more clear: my scenario would mean that the refresh tokens of the one application are stored in the db of the other application but that seems to be a security hole to me. I am trying to find out if that is done in other integration and this seems to be the case in the facebook / spotify integration.

Comment: spotify uses the token of its own facebook app, so why would they store a token of another app? what other app? spotify just offers facebook login with their spotify facebook app, that´s all.

Comment: That's not true: Spotify offered linking your Facebook account to your Spotify account too. And in this case you have a token for Spotify and a Facebook one: I am just trying to figure out where they are stored. See https://support.spotify.com/sk/account_payment_help/account_basics/using-spotify-with-facebook/

Comment: Yes, in this case you have a Facebook token - that is specific to the Spotify Facebook app. So of course Spotify stores it on their servers, because they need it to make calls to the Facebook Graph API from there.

Comment: Well I'm not sure about the "of course" bit, it's not self evident to me, that's why I'm asking the question. It seems to me that the go-to mechanism would be to store all tokens on the end user device (phone, browser etc.). This would have the disadvantage that each device / client would need to reauthorize. It seems like a security risk to me to store tokens in a DB as they basically correspond to unencrypted credentials for potentially large numbers of users.